# Is it possible facebook login without plugin in phonegap?

Tags: facebook, cordova

I have tried the facebook code which  I used while website development but it gives fb not defined error but the same code working for website . Here is the example of the code I am using :

```
FB.login(function(response) {
                        if (response.session) {
                            init();
                                              alert('here');
                        } else {
                            init();
                        }
                    });
```

I have included all javascript files required for this but not working .

Comment: Yes, we can have facebook login without plugin. Here we will get error because the Website URL and device URL are different.

Comment: @jeek Do have any url or example of code which can help me .

Comment: did you include all JAVA files also (for android) and/or .h and .m files for iOS?

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved like :-

```
/** Including fb js file [downloaded from here][1] **/
<script src="sdk.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
/** INIT sdk : mandatory for all fb methods**/

FB.init({
appId      : 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx',  /* Your facebook AppID */
status     : true,
xfbml      : true,
version    : 'v2.0',
});


 /** Login **/

 document.getElementById('login-btn').onclick = function() {
    FB.login(function(response) {
    Log.info('FB.login response', response);
  });
   return false;
 }
</script>
```

[This for your reference](http://hayageek.com/facebook-javascript-sdk/)

Comment: Yes  code is working now but I am facing url issue "Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration" where we can define url for app and what will be the url .

Comment: Follow steps [1] Create Facebook App [2] Add platform - comes in left side 'Settings' menu [3] Specify WEBSITE URL in the field of popup.